# Converting information on a table to date

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to create a loading program to enter a large volume of data files (sorted by date) to a database. 
I'm using part of a code done with `SQL Server` Data Tools by someone else where we create a table with a single cell with the date that we want to load (in the format `YYYY-MM`) as a `string`. 
My problem is that I need to read that cell, convert it to a date and then change its format to display `DDMMYYYY` where `DD` is the last day of the month (so that I can then use it to find the correct file (file names are `prefix_DDMMYYYY.txt`).

I've been trying to use something like cast or convert. But I keep having problems getting the information from the cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the issue you are getting ? And what did you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) = '2015-01'
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, @s + '-01'))
```

or

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, ColumnName + '-01'))
FROM TableName
```

and convert to specific format in your app or use non standart Convert like

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, @s + '-01')), 104) , '.', '')
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, ColumnName  + '-01')), 104) , '.', '')
FROM TableName
```

You will need some hack, because `SQL Server's CONVERT` doesn't have this format `'ddMMyyyy'`. Closest is `dd.mm.yy` or `dd-mm-yy`, but you need `REPLACE` in addition. So I would do conversion in my application.